# R: Ggvis - add_tooltip for bar chart

Tags: r, ggvis

i'm having troubles using the add_tooltip from ggvis.

I just want to put a tool tip for the sessions by source to my plot.

I'm having troubles understanding the html function that needs to be created for add_tooltip()

I understand i need an "ID" within my data (you can see my data at the bottom). Please, may someone explane this part. I don't understand how ggvis uses the ID for the plot.

```
Visitas_Por_Fuente$id <- 1:nrow(Visitas_Por_Fuente) #Create the ID column.




Visitas_Por_Fuente %>%
  ggvis(~Fuentes, ~sessions) %>%
  layer_bars(width = 0.8, fill = ~Fuentes) %>%
  add_tooltip(mysessions ,"hover")


mysessions <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  #notice below the id column is how ggvis can understand which session to show
  row <- Visitas_Por_Fuente[Visitas_Por_Fuente$id == x$id, ]
  #prettyNum shows the number with thousand-comma separator
  paste0("Sessions:", "&nbsp;",prettyNum(row$sessions, big.mark=",",scientific=F))
}
```

The graph is shown, but when hovering says:

```
Warning: Unhandled error in observer: non-character argument
observe({
    value <- session$input[[id]]
    if (is.null(value)) 
        return()
    if (!is.list(value$data)) 
        return()
    df <- value$data
    class(df) <- "data.frame"
    attr(df, "row.names") <- .set_row_names(1L)
    fun(data = df, location = list(x = value$pagex, y = value$pagey), 
        session = session)
})
```

My data:

```
structure(list(Fuentes = structure(c(3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 
1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 
1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 
6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 
1L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 
4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 
6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 
6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 
6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 
5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Adwords", "Campañas", "Directo", 
"Email", "Referencias", "SEO", "Social Media"), class = "factor"), 
    sessions = c(197L, 1L, 7L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 566L, 1L, 27L, 159L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
    6L, 10L, 129L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 28L, 
    1L, 7L, 386L, 1L, 146L, 1L, 89L, 41L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 
    3L, 4L, 182L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 524L, 4L, 26L, 1L, 152L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    5L, 10L, 142L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 
    13L, 3L, 375L, 3L, 2L, 147L, 1L, 101L, 29L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 224L, 3L, 12L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 
    1L, 4L, 141L, 4L, 632L, 2L, 2L, 32L, 1L, 138L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 
    5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 139L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 
    5L, 9L, 8L, 36L, 1L, 537L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 174L, 1L, 106L, 
    39L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 689L, 1L, 14L, 2L, 
    2L, 35L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 20L, 465L, 1L, 3269L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 32L, 6L, 2L, 293L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 
    9L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 433L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 37L, 
    10L, 88L, 6L, 1808L, 5L, 4L, 451L, 5L, 219L, 112L, 4L, 3L, 
    1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 2L, 264L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 
    1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 516L, 1L, 948L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    33L, 1L, 1L, 133L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 11L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    6L, 10L, 5L, 168L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 98L, 1L, 548L, 1L, 1L, 177L, 97L, 17L, 4L, 
    1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 235L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 
    2L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 396L, 1209L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 41L, 1L, 125L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 121L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    10L, 3L, 75L, 5L, 632L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 178L, 1L, 67L, 33L, 6L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 12L, 3L, 194L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 
    1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 296L, 1L, 1L, 979L, 
    6L, 4L, 1L, 33L, 1L, 109L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 118L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    4L, 2L, 1L, 18L, 6L, 53L, 3L, 584L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 172L, 2L, 
    100L, 27L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 3L, 202L, 6L, 
    20L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 292L, 719L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    29L, 106L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 139L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 20L, 53L, 3L, 530L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 172L, 113L, 23L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 891L, 
    10L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1312L, 
    1L, 1L, 1168L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 39L, 133L, 3L, 13L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 3L, 297L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 25L, 182L, 1L, 776L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 260L, 2L, 
    115L, 52L, 14L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 14L, 2L, 731L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 16L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 11L, 6L, 294L, 1L, 1135L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 36L, 1L, 
    1L, 126L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 
    355L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 13L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 22L, 
    5L, 67L, 1L, 2L, 926L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 208L, 1L, 
    1L, 136L, 44L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    8L, 9L, 1L, 198L, 1L, 8L, 13L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 205L, 
    568L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 94L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    8L, 157L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 
    28L, 3L, 444L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 118L, 2L, 75L, 27L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 166L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 203L, 644L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 26L, 1L, 4L, 
    75L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 155L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 36L, 1L, 2L, 446L, 3L, 1L, 99L, 
    86L, 27L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 159L, 1L, 3L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 174L, 
    733L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 22L, 2L, 84L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 100L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 38L, 7L, 502L, 
    2L, 1L, 86L, 6L, 83L, 24L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 321L, 
    8L, 11L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 191L, 1L, 5L, 1417L, 1L, 
    6L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 2L, 1L, 150L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 218L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 16L, 4L, 45L, 1L, 3L, 879L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    207L, 2L, 115L, 44L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 4L, 171L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 178L, 614L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 20L, 1L, 94L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 121L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    7L, 3L, 31L, 1L, 1L, 433L, 1L, 3L, 23L, 94L, 79L, 25L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 160L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 568L, 
    1L, 2L, 5L, 15L, 5L, 86L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 118L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 530L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 121L, 1L, 1L, 72L, 34L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 7L, 4L, 326L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1271L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 17L, 2L, 161L, 3L, 1L, 14L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 195L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 20L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 
    1050L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 196L, 134L, 52L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 120L, 
    1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 371L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 74L, 2L, 
    11L, 1L, 3L, 84L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 14L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 
    1L, 382L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 69L, 1L, 54L, 17L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 168L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    5L, 374L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 69L, 1L, 10L, 6L, 85L, 1L, 1L, 
    16L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 393L, 3L, 17L, 53L, 75L, 22L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 136L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 488L, 1L, 4L, 25L, 1L, 71L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 126L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 445L, 1L, 1L, 90L, 1L, 77L, 20L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 248L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 981L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 
    134L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 194L, 5L, 1L, 16L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 850L, 1L, 1L, 155L, 1L, 117L, 
    43L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 124L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 373L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 63L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 125L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 
    1L, 2L, 287L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 54L, 1L, 49L, 19L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    5L, 8L, 1L, 91L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 289L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 12L, 61L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 2L, 1L, 91L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 
    2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 241L, 1L, 5L, 42L, 1L, 51L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
    4L, 98L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 251L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 47L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 73L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 214L, 2L, 1L, 40L, 41L, 17L, 3L, 2L, 103L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 270L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 21L, 60L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 73L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 219L, 1L, 55L, 60L, 13L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 168L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 404L, 8L, 
    8L, 1L, 99L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 115L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
    3L, 6L, 362L, 1L, 2L, 64L, 2L, 88L, 15L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 104L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 343L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 64L, 2L, 10L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 106L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 286L, 
    1L, 2L, 43L, 2L, 56L, 24L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 140L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 479L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 20L, 
    87L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 118L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 
    4L, 1L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 389L, 1L, 1L, 66L, 1L, 75L, 13L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 98L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    341L, 3L, 1L, 21L, 101L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    85L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 278L, 10L, 67L, 
    2L, 54L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 98L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    315L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 13L, 1L, 59L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    4L, 2L, 90L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 235L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 53L, 72L, 18L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 68L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 241L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 37L, 1L, 1L, 66L, 
    1L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 197L, 47L, 39L, 19L, 1L)), .Names = c("Fuentes", 
"sessions"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1724L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you need to give the layer a "key" to be returned when hovering or clicking it which is then used as input for the tooltip function.

A problem I see here is that you are producing a bar chart (i.e. values are summed up per "Fuente" type) but you want to use a tooltip *for each single observation* (row) in your data. So the problem is that in your chart you don't display each data point (observation) separated and hence it will be difficult, when hovering over a bar, to know what specific data point (observation) you want to return for the tooltip.

In order to show how it might work for `layer_points` with observation-specific tooltips, I adapted your code like this:

```
Visitas_Por_Fuente$id <- 1:nrow(Visitas_Por_Fuente) #Create the ID column.

mysessions <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  # get the current session info, based on "id" that is hovered over:
  current_session <- Visitas_Por_Fuente[Visitas_Por_Fuente$id == x$id, "sessions"]
  # format the value with prettyNum if you like:
  paste0("Sessions:", "&nbsp;",prettyNum(current_session, big.mark=",",scientific=F))
}

Visitas_Por_Fuente %>%
  ggvis(~Fuentes, ~sessions) %>%
  layer_points(fill = ~Fuentes, key := ~id) %>%               # define a key
  add_tooltip(mysessions ,"hover")
```

Here's another version with tool tips for a bar chart showing the total number of sessions per "Fuente" type when hovering over a bar (this is possible because it doesn't require to know what single data point is used - instead we use "Fuente" as key):

```
mysessions <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  # compute the total number of sessions of the "Fuente" type that is hovered over
  total_sessions <- 
      sum(Visitas_Por_Fuente[Visitas_Por_Fuente$Fuentes == x$Fuentes, "sessions"])
  # format the value with prettyNum if you like:
  paste0("Total number of Sessions:", "&nbsp;",
             prettyNum(total_sessions, big.mark=",",scientific=F))
}

Visitas_Por_Fuente %>%
  ggvis(~Fuentes, ~sessions) %>%
  layer_bars(width = 0.8, fill = ~Fuentes, key := ~Fuentes) %>%
  add_tooltip(mysessions ,"hover")
```

Comment: it worked perfect. I've used the "total_sessions" part.

I'll creating a new question for a new problem, when joining this code within Shiny. Thanks again.